# Invoking Activity constructor with JUnit did not throw runtime exception?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, junit, junit4

I was running a test and trying out somethings, and noticed a strange behaviour.

```
@Test
public void setupActivity()
{
    Activity activity = new Activity();
}
```

The above test ran successfully and did not throw a runtime exception.

```
@Test
public void setupActivity()
{
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.isFinishing();
}
```

And this one threw a runtime exception for isFinishing() method.

Why wasn't an exception not thrown for invoking the constructor? 
As I took a look at the code for Activity.class in android.jar and all the methods including the constructor should throw a runtime exception.

```
public Activity() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public boolean isFinishing() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Is it some issue with the JUnit runner? I was using JUnit4 to run my tests.

Answer (score 0):

> Why wasn't an exception not thrown for invoking the constructor?

Because creating an instance of an `Activity` is reasonable and necessary. The framework will create instances of your `Activity` via its constructor as needed based on `startActivity()` requests, configuration changes, etc.

> As I took a look at the code for Activity.class in android.jar and all the methods including the constructor should throw a runtime exception.

You are looking at a decompiled edition of the `android.jar` in your Android SDK. That is not the class that is used at runtime. The version of `Activity` used at runtime will be based on the version of Android on the device, plus perhaps tweaks by device manufacturers. For example, [here is the source to Android 9.0's edition of `Activity`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-9.0_r1/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

Comment: I am using Junit so it is independent of any device. Also, wouldn't instantiating an object call its constructor?

Comment: @shubhamgarg1: "I am using Junit so it is independent of any device" -- perhaps you are writing instrumented tests, not unit tests. "wouldn't instantiating an object call its constructor?" -- it does.

Comment: I am trying to just verify that it throws an exception that you can't use android dependencies in your tests and writing a unit test only. Also, if the constructor is invoked shouldn't an exception be thrown for the first test as well?

Comment: @shubhamgarg1: Perhaps you are using Mockito, and so you are using its implementation of `Activity`.

Comment: For this test as you can see nothing has been mocked and I am running this with default JUnit4 runner.